# SSL Issue Non secure links still reachable by HTTPS

Tags: checkout, magento-1, configuration, ssl, secure

Currently we only require our checkout to be SSL secure. However if we manually type any URL from product page, catalog pages and home page with https:// infront of the domain secure pages are loading. Should magento be redirecting this to http:// as these aren't checkout pages.

Our config is below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**, it won't redirect.

Long answer: Actually you said the point, the pages other than checkout page won't redirect to HTTPS. You CAN use it does not mean you MUST use it. You can still use HTTP to access non-checkout pages. If you want to force HTTPS in all pages, just set the **Unsecure Base URL** to HTTPS.